# Ошибка в подключении к глобальному серверу Python Socket

Tags: python, сервер, сокет

Решил что такое сервер и как его создать.С первым пунктом справился но с его созданием возникла проблема.Для теста решил создать чат для 2 пользователей(я и мой друг).
У меня на пк всё работает хорошо когда другу кинул файл что бы протестить возникла ошибка текст которой я размещу ниже.

Вот так выглядит server.py

```
import socket

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 65432  
print(HOST)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

client.py

```
import socket

HOST = "тут ip которое я получил таким путём socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()) себя на пк" 
PORT = 65432 

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    data = s.recv(1024)

print(f"Received {data!r}")
```

Ошибка которая возникла в client.py у друга на пк

File "C:\Users\Username\Downloads\client.py", line 7, in 
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond